# Where are the display settings located in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: display, settings

Where are the display settings located  in Ubutnu 21.10 ?

Comment: I'm sure they are in the settings somewhere

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-display.html.en    (*Sorry I'm unsure what you're actually after, but I'm not a GNOME user but have found everything I'd want there*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open settings and type  display in the search bar at the top left
[image: settings display here]

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all